# How to change the current line numbers indicator's color?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Installed One Dark Pro theme for Microsoft Visual Studio 2022, I like everything. But it gets annoying when line number active then its color is black, how to change it? I rummaged through the settings in Tools / Options / Fonts and color, but did not find a solution (

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

delved into the settings, googled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the "Line Number (Current)" property in the same window (Tools → Options → Environment → Fonts and Colors):

[image: line number (current) property in the fonts and colors window]

Comment: oh, it was so easy... you just had to look further, sorry)